# Jest - test Vue.js functions declared inside reactive variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Do you know what's the correct way to test functions that are declared inside the reactive variables in **VUE**. To achieve 100% coverage in the component, Jest says is needed to apply test to this functions.

Example: The function **customData** is inside the reactive var **chartOptions** and must be tested:

```
export default{
  name: 'component',
  data: function () {
    chartOptions: {
      customData: function ({ val1 }) {
        return val1 > 0 ? val1 * 2 : 0  
      }
        }
  }
}
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you mount your computed in jest, you can access the function through

```js
wrapper.vm.charOptions.customData
```

Then call the function as you would normally do and test its output. For branch output you probably need to call it twice

Comment: anytime man! Good luck with the rest you got this